# C# Insert multiline text in string at certain position

Tags: c#, string, append, stringbuilder

I have a multiline string in which I want to append some multiline text and
keep the indentation for the appended lines of text. An example probably explains the issue better:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int int1 = 50000;
double double1 = 5800.0;
string test = "Test\r\nSome\r\nMultiline\r\nstuff.";
sb.AppendFormat("{0,8};{1,8};{2}",int1,double1,test);
Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

This will give me the output

```
50000;    5800;Test
Some
Multiline
stuff.
```

However what I wish to attain is

```
50000;    5800;Test
               Some
               Multiline
               stuff.
```

I'm aware there are ways to handle this by writing your own functionality, however I was hoping the StringBuilder class or a similar construct could help me.

Comment: Use `String.Replace` on the `\r\n` to add spaces?  Like `test.Replace("\r\n", "                \r\n";`?  I.e., add 16 spaces before the newline (doesn't look right formatted in comments).

Comment: Yeah, no, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: @Will you can still "do it yourself" with the help of IndentedTextWriter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `System.CodeDom.Compiler.IndentedTextWriter` for an easy solution. It is worth knowing this type anyway, if you have to generate source code or such frequently.

In the end, it is also a `System.Text.StringBuilder`, which is used, as the demo code shows:

```
static void Bar()
{
    int int1 = 50000;
    double double1 = 5800.0;
    string test = "Test\r\nSome\r\nMultiline\r\nstuff.";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
    IndentedTextWriter itw = new IndentedTextWriter(writer, new string(' ', 18));
    itw.Write("{0,8};{1,8};", int1, double1);
    itw.Indent++;
    test.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).All(s => { itw.WriteLine(s); return true; });
    Console.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments have said, you're mostly going to have to write your own. It's not much code though:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int int1 = 50000;
        double double1 = 5800.0;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,8};{1,8};");
        var indentation = "".PadLeft(sb.Length);
        var test = "Test\r\nSome\r\nMultiline\r\nstuff.";
        var testLines = test.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (int i=0; i<testLines.Length;i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", "\r\n", indentation);
            }
            sb.Append(testLines[i]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
```

You could do some other stuff but if you have a dynamic length of indent, you would have to build your format strings to include the indentation amount which seems like more effort than it's worth to me.

Answer (score -1):

code:

```
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("First Name | Last Name  |   Age");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Bill", "Gates", 51));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny", "Depp", 44));
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
```

output:

```
-------------------------------
First Name | Last Name  |   Age
-------------------------------
Bill       | Gates      |    51
Edna       | Parker     |   114
Johnny     | Depp       |    44
-------------------------------
```

source:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/